# Display only the last line of a windows command line executable

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, batch-file, redirection, stdout

I'm trying to write a batch script that manages simple software deployments. One of the steps in the script compresses a file structure into a 7zip archive.

During the compression process, the z7ip command line application outputs the current file that is being archived with a percentage indicator. By the end of this process the output is quite long. I would like to reduce the output to a single line because I really only care about the percentage indicator.

Does anyone know of a utility I can redirect the output into that will only display the last line as it comes in? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thou shalt use Powershell for all new scripts.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426442/unix-tail-equivalent-command-in-windows-powershell

Comment: Came here to say exactly what @Zoredache said. You're better off investing in learning PowerShell than batch scripts.